# What's the difference between looper and a while loop in thread proccessing?

Tags: android, multithreading

What's the difference between looper and a while loop in thread proccessing?
i tried this code and it works just like i used a Handler with Looper:

```
public abstract class han {
public abstract void handleMessage(Message message);
public void sendMessage(Message message)
{
    handleMessage(message);
}
}
```

and then:

```
                while (0 == 0) {
                h = new han() {
                    @Override
                    public void handleMessage(Message message) {
                        Toast.makeText(thr.this, "mm", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                };
```

actually, "han" is a class like Handler, but because the Handler errors without looper, i made a special class to do that called: "han".  and "h" is a global variable

Comment: Are you trying to make tons of instances of han?

Comment: your answer is under the next answer

Comment: The task of looper in android is retrieving the messages from message queue and ensure the message is handled on correct handler. If there is no message in the message queue , it will block and wait for the incoming message. The convenient looper class exist in **android.os.Looper**. 

**While loop** on the other hand,  might not able to that intelligent to determine to execute on correct handler and thread

Answer (score 0):

In short at looper is a convenience class that runs in a Thread.
From the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html

"Class used to run a message loop for a thread." So what it says is that a looper allows you to send messages to threads that instaniated one. I now presumably, but I don't think it would use up resources until it receives messages, probably by a smart synchronisation / wait combination inside the looper.

Now your while loop will run indefinitely and create new han object, which is very often. You should see the Garbage collector run to collect those objects. But yes, your code should work and you should be able to receive messages but at a big cost of resouces. (And if you don't run in a while loop your thread will finish and nothing will happen, this is what the looper prevents.)

Comment: OK, but i can remove abstract label from han (but still override handleMessage), and define the instance before the loop, and then just handle the message under the loop.